# 404 connecting frontend to backend, content security policy

Tags: reactjs, express, content-security-policy

I have the backend server.js file in a folder labeled server alongside a client folder.  I have express, cors, and nodemon installed as dependencies in the server folder, and performed a CRA to generate the front end.

However, I created an endpoint to return a json object to test if the server is working and it is not.

Step 1:
First,  I attempted to set the "/" endpoint to return a res.send({message: "welcome to the server"})  and display it on the dom.

RESULT:

Cannot Get /

---In the Console of the Chrome browser I see a 404  for the path http://localhost:5000/weather although I've defined the endpoint as instructed, and in Firefox Dev Edition I see that the Content Security Policy blocked a resource http://localhost:5000/favicon

Step 2:
This lead me to attempt a HTTP response header that would include the security policy directives being violated.

Step 3:
Hereafter I learned that the diagnostics are throwing this error because servers by their nature do not serve the contents of the root directory, therefore  I included a static path for the folder where that resource would be located to circumvent the cause of the 404 error. I lastly updated the file path in index.html where the /favicon.ico is being referenced and removed the %public% from its url so that it is an exact path to the public folder

Step 4:

Because the combination of configuring the Content Security Policy HTTP request header, updating the path for the server to resolve to the public client folder, and opening it in different browsers did not work. I tried one final thing that I've read from mining stack overflow: removing the devtools.JSONview.enabled from my Firefox browser. To no avail..

What could be the source of this problem? I've tried every solution ive seen so far.. is there something I've overlooked? Does Helmut really fix this issue? If so, what directive would it add that I haven't already? Please, and Thank you

Setting Response Header to include Content Security Policy with relevant directives,

Updating the file path of the favicon.ico resource and setting a static path for express to locate missing directory,

And updating browser settings in Firefox, attempted in Chrome to no avail.

Comment: can you share your code sample?

Comment: My apologies for never replying to this. I posted the code example from the mobile side and I see that it was never published. Lastly, I solved the problem. As the other SO articles suggest, improper error handling causes the Browser to throw a Content Security Policy error when in reality its non related. My issue was that I put my error handle prior to the code to be executed, and therefore there was no code for the compiler to see when it was time to run. Thanks for your willingness to help.